# Asp.net Core 1.0 project.json prepublish scripts

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core

Hey this is a part of my project.json file:

```
  "scripts": {
        "prepublish": [
          "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js",
          "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"
        ],
        "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
      },
```

I want to invoke prepublish scripts every time I publish the application even if it's a development environment and I am running it through visual studio or dotnet run. `Prepublish` doesn't seem to work in these cases

Comment: As far as I know, pre/post publish only work when you actually `publish` the application (ex: dotnet publish) and not on dotnet run

Comment: This is what I suspected, how should I handle that then?

Comment: You could use a postcompile script

Comment: I do but it takes 30 second so I don't want to rebuild it every time.

Answer (score 1):

When you run through VS or using 'dotnet run', you only build and run the application from source, without publishing. Publishing scripts will be triggered, if you call `dotnet publish`.

> The dotnet run command provides a convenient option to run your application from the source code with one command. It compiles source code, generates an output program and then runs that program.

Right now only [the following types of script are supported](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/04f40f906dce2678d80fb9787e68de76ee6bf57e/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils/ScriptNames.cs):

- precompile
- postcompile
- prepublish
- postpublish

and what you want is more like "beforerun"/"postrun". As a workaround you may try to call your scripts directly from code in your application entry point.